# How to compare group of Strings

Tags: java, string, compare

I have the following code..

```
    WorkPackage spack=(WorkPackage)primaryBusinessObject;
    WTSet res;
    WTPart spart=null;
    String state=null;

res=wt.facade.persistedcollection.PersistedCollectionHelper.service.getAllMembers(spack);

    System.out.println("the values are "+res);

    java.util.Iterator iter=res.persistableIterator();
    while(iter.hasNext())
    {
        spart=(wt.part.WTPart) iter.next();
        wt.lifecycle.LifeCycleState st=spart.getState();

        String state=st.toString();                 //Lifecycle state of part object
    }
    if(state.contains("APPROVED"))
        result="Proceed";
```

In the above code I'm passing a windchill package and it may have muliple number of WTPart objects.Each part may have different life cycle states.What I want is if every part state is "APPROVED" means it should proceed in my workflow.

For eg.

LifeCycle states of

```
 Part1=IN WORK
 Part2=IN REVIEW
 Part3=APPROVED
 Part4=APPROVED
 Part5=CANCELED
```

I want to compare all the objects from my package is `APPROVED` I can store these in vector or a arraylist and I don't know how to compare all the objects from that.My above code will pass if any one of objects state is APPROVED.I know this question not related to windchill.Somebody help me out of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you store all of the states in an `ArrayList<String> states` then you can test if they are all APPROVED using something like:

```
boolean allApproved = true;

for(int i = 0; i < states.size(); i++) {
    if(!states.get(i).equals("APPROVED") {
        allApproved = false;
    }
}
```

At the end of the for loop, if allApproved is still true, you're good to go.